# How to pull a random object from a list and remove it in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a rotational schedule in Excel that will randomly assign a building once a week without duplicates. I need each building to have a morning/afternoon shift and alternate the following week.

So what I was thinking is there are 20 shifts every 2 weeks, Morning/Afternoon 5 days a week and I have 10 buildings to go to so that works out nicely. I want it to be random so that way I am not always in the same building at the same time every week.

So I used  `=RAND()` in Column B of sheet 1 to generate a random number for each building and then pasted it as just values to get rid of the formula in that column.

Then on sheet 2, I tried having `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11, RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11)))` in each cell of 5x4 schedule.

The problem is there are duplicates and I want the second week to actually be opposite morning/afternoon but still random days. I think that I'll probably have to have it randomize morning/afternoon the first week, then do days and the second week have it opposite whatever the random morning/afternoon was and then do random days again but I'm just not sure how to go about it.

I'm new to programming in Excel and my programming is a little rusty in general...

EDIT: I was able to use `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"Morning","Afternoon")` to have a column choose morning/afternoon randomly but it doesn't ensure equal number of mornings to afternoons which I need. And I still wouldn't know how to have the opposite results elsewhere for the following week.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use if condition to make sure you select opposite morning/afternoon after you selected random days.

like this:

=IF(AND(B3="Morning",C3="Morning"),"Afternoon",IF(AND(B3="Afternoon",C3="Afternoon"),"Morning",C3))

Comment: That..sort of helps solve my opposites problem. I still need to figure out random days without duplicates. I was hoping I could use an array or list and then once it's used, remove it.